# Running my own compiled apk as system app

Tags: android

Let's say, for example, I cloned the Phone application from AOSP, alter it and compiled it into an APK. Would I be able to push it onto a rooted phone and still work?

Are there any security checks like signature verifications involved? I know it should be possible, custom roms have modified APKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "system" APK are just regular APK which were preinstalled in specific location. So, yes, you can replace them by your own (signed by your own key). Even more, you can remove system APK from "syslem" location and install the replacement as regular application. At least I did that many times for my Galaxy S.